# Why $\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{1}{x^{-1}+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need some help understanding why $\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{1}{x^{-1}+1}$.

I would be grateful if someone could explain. Be explicit.

Thank you!

Comment: How is this algebraic number theory?

Comment: @Asaf: It isn't. You should feel free to do tag edits when you see any that are so off (you have more than enough reputation for it).

Comment: Sorry for the mistag. On a second thought, this was so easy there's only one correct answer - don't do maths on a friday night.

Comment: Arturo, I usually do. From time to time I use my iPhone to actively use the site, at which case I just tend to be a jerk about it. :-)

Comment: It might be helpful to note, that there is a blow-up at -1, as expected while at 0 the right expression is formally undefined, but it makes sense give it the value 0 (by continouos extension, if you know this). Plotting this function might help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{x \cdot 1}{x \cdot (1+\frac{1}{x})}= \frac{x}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}} = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1}{1+x^{-1}}$$

Comment: When $x \neq 0$.

Comment: ..and when $x\neq -1$

Answer (score 4):

Your equation is not correct.  Note that the expression on the left-hand side is defined for $x=0$, but the right-hand expression is not.  Thus, the two expressions are not equivalent.  However, assuming $x\neq 0$, we may transform the left-hand expression into the right-hand expression as tpv has shown.

In particular to tpv's explanation, note that $\frac{x}{x}=1$ only if $x \neq 0$.

Comment: #Matthew: It is correct as an identity of rational functions, i.e. polynomial fractions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Bill.  Can you elaborate? For instance, the denominator of the rhs is not a polynomial, so I'm not clear what you intend by saying this is an identity of polynomial fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Divide both the numerator and the denominator by $x$.